# Mirror Apple TV screen to macOS

Tags: macos, mac, appletv, mirroring

Is there anyway to mirror the Apple TV screen to macOS?
For the cases where you don't have a TV set (or have someone hogging a TV set all day long), but an Apple TV. And a Mac.

Comment: I don't think you can. Wouldn't it make more sense to just login to the service via web browser? Like let's say you want to watch Netflix through apple tv... so what you do is login to Netflix.com. Or you want to listen to Apple music, so you open up iTunes and login there. I can somewhat see the appeal of streaming from a device where everything is already setup, but I don't think it's necessary as Apple TV itself is just streaming content to your TV from different services, so you can just go to the source directly.

Comment: The Apple TV is not a service with which you login using a browser. I just want to mirror the screen it displays to a view in my macOS. Or something like and iPad, or whatever.

Comment: Yes, but apple tv is essentially a collection of services. My point is that you don't need apple tv to use those services on a computer. You don't get the same UI and you have to login to each service separately, but nothing is stopping you from using those same services without apple tv. Apparently, if you have Apple TV 4 (I believe) you can do it: [Mirroring Apple TV to a Mac](https://luisperezonline.com/2015/11/10/mirroring-apple-tv-to-a-mac/)

Comment: My point is not to use those services. My point is to mirror the Apple TV screen to my computer.

Comment: If you are not using any services of the apple tv, what is the point of mirroring it to anything? You might as well just open up a picture of the apple tv interface and be done with it.

Comment: If you ever used an Apple TV you might know that is has standalone games etc etc and you can make your own apps etc etc. I am.

Comment: No need to get upset. Q&A sites are filled with questions that could be solved in a different way, but OP is too stubborn or withholding information in the belief that the solution they're looking for is the way to go, which is why I kept pushing the point that you don't need apple tv to login to Netflix for instance. I don't have Apple TV 4. I did give you a link to an article that tells you how to do it with apple tv 4.

Comment: Q&A sites are also filled with people who don't read the questions properly. For the Nth time, my purpose is not to use services like Netflix. You don't need to answer.

Comment: I read the question just fine. It took 3 comments for you to mention that you wanted to use it for playing games and software development, which changes the question in the sense that you'd need something like screen mirroring to do those things. Or at least the gaming part. Lack of information coupled with the fact that I don't know everything about Apple TV's is why I'm commenting and not answering the question. Again though. I did give you that link. Check it out.

Comment: I understand it's been a while since you originally asked this question. However, I am fairly sure you can do this through the QuickTime player on a Mac as long as you've paired the Apple TV of course as this would allow you to screen share but you would still need to use the Apple TV remote to control.